# Factory function from base type to derived type

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I'm trying to implement a factory function that accepts a base type and returns a new generic class with a derived type depending on what type the base type is, like so:

```
public IStaffingEventValidator<T> GetValidator<T>(T staffingEvent)
        {
            switch (staffingEvent)
            {
                case HireEvent ev:
                    return (IStaffingEventValidator<T>)new HireEventValidator();

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that type T is a base `StaffingEvent`, and `HireEventValidator` is of type `IStaffingEventValidator<HireEvent>`, where `HireEvent` is a `StaffingEvent`.

I know this is not working because of covariance and contravariance, my question is how should I rather be implementing something like this? Is this a bad design? I have a list of `StaffingEvents` and want to create a validator using the derived type for each of them.

Comment: So, does that mean you have a inheritance hierarchy like "StaffingEvent" , "SomeEvent:StaffingEvent" , "SomeOtherEvent:StaffingEvent" ... ?

Comment: Something along this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xz8nrM ?

Comment: Include your class design in the question

Comment: @Fildor yes exactly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks fine. However I can suggest you another implementation with OO.

```
class Helper
    {
        public StaffingEventValidator GetValidator<T>(T staffingEvent)
        {
            switch (staffingEvent)
            {
                case HireEvent ev:
                    return new HireEventValidator(ev);
                // Others...
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }

    class StaffingEvent
    {

    }

    class HireEvent : StaffingEvent
    {

    }

    class StaffingEventValidator
    {
        public StaffingEventValidator(StaffingEvent ev)
        {
            
        }
    }

    class HireEventValidator : StaffingEventValidator
    {
        public HireEventValidator(StaffingEvent ev) : base(ev)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the architecture of this. I've implemented something similar before also. It's a bit complicated to describe, so I'll directly give some example code

```
public class StaffingEventBase<TValidator> where TValidator : IStaffingEventValidator, new()
{
    public TValidator GetValidator()
    {
        return new TValidator();
    }
}

public class HireEvent : StaffingEventBase<HireEventValidator>
{

}

public class HireEventValidator : IStaffingEventValidator
{
}

public interface IStaffingEventValidator
{
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hireEvent = new HireEvent();
    
    // Here retrieved the correct validator.
    var validator = hireEvent.GetValidator();
}
```

Working here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/VDqPGN

Comment: Try with `StaffingEvent hireEvent = new HireEvent();`

Comment: We don't need `Activator.CreateInstance`. Add `new()` constraint and return `new TValidator()`.

Comment: @N.Dogac Yes, you are right. I've edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: That's cheated. OP obviously has a non-generic base. This example is as good as saying "ditch the base class". You could never have, say a `IEnumerable<StaffingEvent>` in which there are different children. You'd be stuck with concrete `IEnumerble<StaffingEventBase<SomeConcreteValidator>>`. Maybe you can improve this by introducing a non-generic interface for StaffingEvents?

Comment: @Fildor Yes. In that case we can have an `IStaffingEvent` interface. So we will have IEnumerable<IStaffingEvent> instead. The example I've given was just to show a miminal code.

Comment: I totally get that. I just found it didn't _perfectly_ match OP's requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KorayElbek. I went with N. Dogac's answer because I don't really like being forced to specify the validator in the declaration of the `HireEvent`, but it would have worked fine too. Thanks!

Comment: @Murray Thanks. And to be honest, it's good to be forced to declare a validator in the Event classes. Otherwise you might forget to add one validator, or forget to update the `switch` in the future & you won't have compile time errors, you'll get `ArgumentException` during runtime. According to N. Dogac's answer. And that happens a lot. Especially in office enviroments. Where a lot of different programmers working on the same stuff.